# Zig's filesystem example doesn't work on windows

Tags: windows, filesystems, zig

I am learning zig from [this site](https://ziglearn.org/chapter-2/). I'm on windows with wsl2 installed. This is zig version:

```
$ zig version
0.11.0-dev.2985+3f3b1a680
```

I use git bash for everything mentioned here.

I encountered a problem while learning about filesystem. This example doesn't work on my machine (CTRL+F "make dir"  [here](https://ziglearn.org/chapter-2/) to find it):

```
test "make dir" {
    try std.fs.cwd().makeDir("test-tmp");
    const iter_dir = try std.fs.cwd().openIterableDir(
        "test-tmp",
        .{},
    );
    defer {
        std.fs.cwd().deleteTree("test-tmp") catch unreachable;
    }

    _ = try iter_dir.dir.createFile("x", .{});
    _ = try iter_dir.dir.createFile("y", .{});
    _ = try iter_dir.dir.createFile("z", .{});

    var file_count: usize = 0;
    var iter = iter_dir.iterate();
    while (try iter.next()) |entry| {
        if (entry.kind == .File) file_count += 1;
    }

    try expect(file_count == 3);
}
```

The cleanup line executes the catch unreachable, meaning that `deleteTree(...)` call fails in this line:

```
std.fs.cwd().deleteTree("test-tmp") catch unreachable;
```

Here is the error I see. Somewhere EBUSY error comes up.

```
C:\zig\zig-windows-x86_64-0.11.0-dev.2985+3f3b1a680\lib\std\os\windows.zig:935:31: 0x7ff656a5edc2 in DeleteFile (test.exe.obj)
        .SHARING_VIOLATION => return error.FileBusy,
                              ^
C:\zig\zig-windows-x86_64-0.11.0-dev.2985+3f3b1a680\lib\std\os.zig:2468:5: 0x7ff656a4c221 in unlinkatW (test.exe.obj)
    return windows.DeleteFile(sub_path_w, .{ .dir = dirfd, .remove_dir = remove_dir });
    ^
C:\zig\zig-windows-x86_64-0.11.0-dev.2985+3f3b1a680\lib\std\fs.zig:1914:25: 0x7ff656a18e0a in deleteDirW (test.exe.obj)
            else => |e| return e,
                        ^
C:\zig\zig-windows-x86_64-0.11.0-dev.2985+3f3b1a680\lib\std\fs.zig:1889:13: 0x7ff656a0c49e in deleteDir (test.exe.obj)
            return self.deleteDirW(sub_path_w.span());
            ^
C:\zig\zig-windows-x86_64-0.11.0-dev.2985+3f3b1a680\lib\std\fs.zig:2216:29: 0x7ff656a0377f in deleteTree (test.exe.obj)
                else => |e| return e,
                            ^
C:\Users\user\Documents\zigg\third-steps\src\stuff2.zig:74:51: 0x7ff656a02b77 in test.make dir (test.exe.obj)
        std.fs.cwd().deleteTree("test-tmp") catch unreachable;
                                                  ^
C:\zig\zig-windows-x86_64-0.11.0-dev.2985+3f3b1a680\lib\test_runner.zig:177:28: 0x7ff656a13b2e in mainTerminal (test.exe.obj)
        } else test_fn.func();
                           ^
C:\zig\zig-windows-x86_64-0.11.0-dev.2985+3f3b1a680\lib\test_runner.zig:37:28: 0x7ff656a04905 in main (test.exe.obj)
        return mainTerminal();
                           ^
C:\zig\zig-windows-x86_64-0.11.0-dev.2985+3f3b1a680\lib\std\start.zig:377:41: 0x7ff656a046a7 in WinStartup (test.exe.obj)
    std.debug.maybeEnableSegfaultHandler();
                                        ^
???:?:?: 0x7ffb3875269c in ??? (KERNEL32.DLL)
???:?:?: 0x7ffb39d8a9f7 in ??? (ntdll.dll)
error: the following test command failed with exit code 3:
C:\Users\user\Documents\zigg\third-steps\zig-cache\o\3d7c85ec680dad6ca22ab16356c3a336\test.exe
```

What could be the problem? The example is copied 1 to 1 from the learning resource. Is it unique to me, or does it not work for many people is also what I wonder (maybe the example is outdated).

What I tried: I tried running it, not much to say. I also wasn't able to find anything about "zig deleteTree not working" or "zig deleteTree EBUSY" online.
Maybe I should mention, that I remembered to remove the directory manually after test fails to do so.

Actually, only now I realized, that the directory is empty after test runs. This probably means that deleteTree removes the contents successfully. However, I expected the directory to be removed too, and no runtime errors.

Note: other tests from [the learning resource I use](https://ziglearn.org/) up to this point worked fine.

Comment: ziglearn and zig has been fixed since
gonna link to some github issues thread later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in the example code. It's missing the `close()` call for `iter_dir`. Update the code like this:

```
    var iter_dir = try std.fs.cwd().openIterableDir(
        "test-tmp",
        .{},
    );
    defer {
        iter_dir.close();
        std.fs.cwd().deleteTree("test-tmp") catch unreachable;
    }
```

Comment: now it hangs :/

Comment: it doesn't exit deleteTree, but it removes the files from dir

Comment: That's weird. It works for me. At least on version 0.11.0-dev.1491+2b27bc2c6.

Comment: Indeed, it hangs on your version or the latest (dev.3000). But if I open the folder it instantly fails with FileBusy error.

Comment: so the original example didn't work on dev.1491 meaning it is buggy or super outdated? and with your change it works on dev.1491, but hangs on newest versions? just want to get things straight.

Comment: not sure how to use zig's older version (switch version using `zig <something>`). Or does it have to be new install?

Comment: I think it's a bug in ziglearn's examples. I've made a [PR](https://github.com/Sobeston/ziglearn/pull/166), we'll see how the author responds. Plus, there's a bug in Zig's standard library. Possibly this [one](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/issues/15465).

Comment: I'm not aware of any tool to automatically install specific versions of Zig. I simply replace `c:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Zig\` whenever I need to use a different version.

Comment: Okay, there seems to be another bug in the example: it creates 3 files, but doesn't close them. Combined with the previously mentioned bug in the Zig's standard library, this causes the test to hang forever.